# CSS Input not working correctly in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have been looking at checkboxes and inputs, specifically the submit type, and i found that ALL the browsers that i have display them slightly differently. I always knew there were slight differences, but i thought that the size would be standard at least.
I have taken images of the normal, hover and active states of an input submit button from 5 major browsers and am displaying them at 300% so as to see the differences clearer. Beneath this, i have a REAL browser default input button.
It works in all browser but IE. The hover style seems to interfere with the real button's hover effect. It hasn't got a class and isn't even within a div, so i don't understand why my div.class style is affecting the input. This happens all the way down to IE7, at which point the button behaves normally, but the css:active state no longer works, and at IE5 both hover and active no longer work. Guess they didn't support them? Here is my code...thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Button Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />

<style>
    .ie11 {
        width: 215px;
        height: 70px;
        background: url('images/buttonIE11.png') no-repeat;
    }
    .ie11:hover {
        background: url('images/buttonIE11Hover.png') no-repeat;    
    }
    .ie11:active {
        background: url('images/buttonIE11Active.png') no-repeat;   
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <span>IE 11</span>      
    <div class="ie11"></div>    
    <br />
    <span>Browser Default</span>
    <form>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I couldn't figure out how to format code in the comments :/
I have got it right down to this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>.ie11:hover {}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
```

That style, and it can be any class, is somehow interfering with IE's Input button, and i can't figure out why. The hover function of the input button no longer works. It doesn't do anything on hover. Incidentally, if you activate it, keep the mouse pressed and move off the button, you can then see the hover state until you let go of the mouse.

Comment: `*{box-sizing: border-box;}` to the rescue.

Comment: Also, use HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE html>` instead

Comment: Your code is not useful. Try to add a working example. Upload the images to an external service (like postimage.org) and convert your code in a stacksnippet (we can convert instead of you, but you need to attach the images)

Comment: How does it affect the input?

Comment: HI, i changed the doctype, but it had no affect. I'm still looking into your other suggestion. I was just wondering why? Isn't that for html5? I thought using xhtml would ensure better compatibility between all browsers old and new?

Comment: @Marcos. I'm not sure yet how to do what you ask, but do you really need a working example? I've edited the above post, because i didn't know how to do it in comments. All there is is an input button and a style (with no style), which should not affect the input in anyway. In fact it shouldn't affect anything at all, but it seems to. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further experimenting i think i have found my answer.
I tried an ID instead of class, div, span, img etc. It would seem that IE doesn't like you to use :hover on anything other than a link tag. Not sure of the reason why, but the button now works as it should.
In case anyone is interested to see what the Input element looks like in different browsers, i made a snippet, i think. Hope it works...

```css
a {
 display: block;
}

a.chrome {
 width: 197px;
 height: 63px;
 background: url('http://s31.postimg.org/gspnlvlaz/button_Chrome.png') no-repeat;
}
a.chrome:hover {
 background: url('http://s31.postimg.org/ywso6iizf/button_Chrome_Hover.png') no-repeat; 
}
a.chrome:active {
 background: url('http://s31.postimg.org/7bzuf91gb/button_Chrome_Active.png') no-repeat; 
}

a.ie11 {
 width: 215px;
 height: 70px;
 background: url('http://s31.postimg.org/jph9zwgij/button_IE11.png') no-repeat;
}
a.ie11:hover {
 background: url('http://s31.postimg.org/wd1mq5kt7/button_IE11_Hover.png') no-repeat; 
}
a.ie11:active {
 background: url('http://s31.postimg.org/xa81z0wbf/button_IE11_Active.png') no-repeat; 
}

a.opera {
 width: 195px;
 height: 61px;
 background: url('http://s31.postimg.org/5ghnhu1zv/button_Opera.png') no-repeat;
}
a.opera:hover {
 background: url('http://s31.postimg.org/m5j3dqyl7/button_Opera_Hover.png') no-repeat; 
}
a.opera:active {
 background: url('http://s31.postimg.org/gwo2fvg63/button_Opera_Active.png') no-repeat; 
}

a.safari {
 width: 193px;
 height: 60px;
 background: url('http://s31.postimg.org/k7cffr63f/button_Safari.png') no-repeat;
}
a.safari:hover {
 background: url('http://s31.postimg.org/ttb1t63kr/button_Safari_Hover.png') no-repeat; 
}
a.safari:active {
 background: url('http://s31.postimg.org/gnvjn29p7/button_Safari_Active.png') no-repeat; 
}

a.ff {
 width: 202px;
 height: 60px;
 background: url('http://s31.postimg.org/5zi5dd40r/button_FF.png') no-repeat;
}
a.ff:hover {
 background: url('http://s31.postimg.org/xj11b7jq3/button_FFHover.png') no-repeat; 
}
a.ff:active {
 background: url('http://s31.postimg.org/z0mhmrogr/button_FFActive.png') no-repeat; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <title>Button Test</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
 <span>Chrome. Size = 300%</span>
 <a class="chrome" href="#"></a>
 <br />
 <span>IE 11. Size = 300%</span>  
 <a class="ie11" href="#"></a>
 <br />
 <span>Opera. Size = 300%</span>  
 <a class="opera" href="#"></a>
 <br />
 <span>Safari. Size = 300%</span>  
 <a class="safari" href="#"></a>
 <br />
 <span>FireFox. Size = 300%</span>  
 <a class="ff" href="#"></a>
 <br />
 <span>Browser Default. Size = 100%</span>
 <form>
  <input type="submit" value="Register" />
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
input, select, textarea {   box-sizing: border-box;   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }
```

so you can have the same size on all browsers

Comment: Will look into it soon. I'm just getting a bit hung up on this strange behaviour in IE. Thank you :)